# async computation that have a deadlock in a WPF application and not in a console application

Tags: c#, async-await

I have tried to a reproduce a situation with a deadlock like in this example:

> https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

here is a code I run in console application:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task<int> f()
    {
        var t = Task.Delay(1000);  //and not Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await t;
        return 1; // line execute in a woker thread
    }
    static async Task g()
    {
        int p=await f();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t=g(); //0
        t.Wait();
    }
}
```

this code don't block: return 1 is execture in another thread although i have not writen Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);

But this wpf application has a deadlock as i have forseen:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication3.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
         Startup="Application_Startup">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

```
    public partial class App : Application
{


    public async Task<int> f()
    {

        var t = Task.Delay(1000)
        await t;
        return 1;
    }
    public async Task g()
    {
        int p = await f();
        a = 1 + p;
    }
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {

        var t = g();
        t.Wait();

    }
}
```

I do not understand why the the console application works without deadlock but the wpf application have a deadlock.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Trying to grok the async plumbing rarely gets you anywhere.  There is a much more universal coding rule that always applies: never block the main thread of a GUI app.  You must never use while(true) {}, never loop until the user clicks a button, never call any kind of WaitXxx() method, never wait for a thread to complete.  That gums up the dispatcher of the UI thread, it can no longer dispatch anything, and deadlock is almost always the result.  It is otherwise easy to debug, use the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window and look at the call stack of the Main thread.

Comment: I don't agree with this, a lot comes out of grokking stuff as a developer, and async code is no different. Here the Pierre-olivier had a burning question about how something works, and now has learnt the answer, this is what this site is all about! Memorizing a list of rules is good sometimes, but sometimes going to first principles is more effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/:

`SynchronizationContext.Current` is null in console applications and thus avoids the deadlock described in the post by Stephen Cleary.